# In Jupyter Notebook, how can I restart my kernel after running a function then running another one programmatically?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Each iteration of a function ends up opening thousands of files, so I end up exceeding the file limit.

How can I restart the kernel programmatically, or how can I clear the loaded files after each iteration of the function?